# How to deal with dynamic nested json payload?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to loop through this in logic app but failing. Looping for each array is fine, although when the objects get nested its proving difficult. What would be the best way to handle this? Can it be done in a logic app (without a paid addon)?

My first thought was to flatten it out but unsure how to go about it in logic app.

Payload example:

```
{
  "result_ok": true,
  "total_count": 8,
  "page": 1,
  "total_pages": 1,
  "results_per_page": "500",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "8",
      "contact_id": "",
      "status": "Complete",
      "is_test_data": "1",
      "date_submitted": "2023-09-12 16:32:30 GMT",
      "session_id": "888",
      "language": "English",
      "date_started": "2023-09-12 16:32:30 GMT",
      "link_id": null,
      "url_variables": [
        
      ],
      "ip_address": "567.324.21.0.0",
      "referer": "https://als.check.org/apples/888",
      "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
      "response_time": null,
      "data_quality": [
        
      ],
      "longitude": "-0.81",
      "latitude": "51.4",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "city": "",
      "region": "",
      "postal": "",
      "dma": "0",
      "survey_data": {
        "6": {
          "id": 6,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "Number of people with 3 legs",
          "subquestions": {
            "9": {
              "10012": {
                "id": 10012,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 6,
                "question": "April 23 : All ages",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10013": {
                "id": 10013,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 6,
                "question": "April 23 : Children",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "10": {
              "10012": {
                "id": 10012,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 6,
                "question": "May 23 : All ages",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10013": {
                "id": 10013,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 6,
                "question": "May 23 : Children",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "11": {
              "10012": {
                "id": 10012,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 6,
                "question": "June 23 : All ages",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10013": {
                "id": 10013,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 6,
                "question": "June 23 : Children",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 4,
          "shown": false
        },
        "21": {
          "id": 21,
          "type": "TEXTBOX",
          "question": "Age-standardised avoidable shopping",
          "section_id": 3,
          "shown": false
        },
        "25": {
          "id": 25,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "People with 3 legs who report having a very good or good experience at their last hospital appointment",
          "subquestions": {
            "26": {
              "10032": {
                "id": 10032,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 25,
                "question": "Please complete the following: : Number of question responses",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10033": {
                "id": 10033,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 25,
                "question": "Please complete the following: : Number of 'Very good' responses",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10035": {
                "id": 10035,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 25,
                "question": "Please complete the following: : Number of 'Good' responses",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 22,
          "shown": false
        },
        "28": {
          "id": 28,
          "type": "MENU",
          "question": "who are you?",
          "section_id": 10,
          "answer": "Jayne Thomas",
          "answer_id": 10477,
          "shown": true
        },
        "35": {
          "id": 35,
          "type": "RADIO",
          "question": "Are you an EGG?",
          "section_id": 10,
          "answer": "Yes, I am the EGG",
          "answer_id": 10048,
          "shown": true
        },
        "58": {
          "id": 58,
          "type": "MENU",
          "question": "What is the name of the initiative that you are reporting EGG for?",
          "section_id": 10,
          "shown": false
        },
        "171": {
          "id": 171,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "Percentage of EGGS who report that one of the main reasons for using the kitchen name or logo is that they feel it is a trusted brand",
          "section_id": 16,
          "options": {
            "10199": {
              "id": 10199,
              "option": "April 23",
              "answer": "King. 'It began with."
            },
            "10716": {
              "id": 10716,
              "option": "May 23",
              "answer": "The judge, by the."
            },
            "10717": {
              "id": 10717,
              "option": "June 23",
              "answer": "Alice was more than."
            }
          },
          "shown": true
        },
        "179": {
          "id": 179,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "Difference in the average (median) age at EGG for people with the general population",
          "subquestions": {
            "181": {
              "10200": {
                "id": 10200,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 179,
                "question": "2019/20 : Women",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10201": {
                "id": 10201,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 179,
                "question": "2019/20 : Men",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 3,
          "shown": false
        },
        "272": {
          "id": 272,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "Number of community members consulted to develop local EGGs ",
          "subquestions": {
            "300": {
              "10438": {
                "id": 10438,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 272,
                "question": "April 23 : Total number of people consulted",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "301": {
              "10438": {
                "id": 10438,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 272,
                "question": "May 23 : Total number of people consulted",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "393": {
              "10438": {
                "id": 10438,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 272,
                "question": "June 23 : Total number of people consulted",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 24,
          "shown": false
        },
        "273": {
          "id": 273,
          "type": "TEXTBOX",
          "question": "What is the name of your EGG project?",
          "section_id": 10,
          "shown": false
        },
        "343": {
          "id": 343,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "Number of social media engagement: ",
          "subquestions": {
            "344": {
              "10517": {
                "id": 10517,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "April 23 : Twitter",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10518": {
                "id": 10518,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "April 23 : Facebook",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10519": {
                "id": 10519,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "April 23 : Instagram",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10520": {
                "id": 10520,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "April 23 : LinkedIn",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10521": {
                "id": 10521,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "April 23 : YouTube",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10522": {
                "id": 10522,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "April 23 : Health Unlocked",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "345": {
              "10517": {
                "id": 10517,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "May 23 : Twitter",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10518": {
                "id": 10518,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "May 23 : Facebook",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10519": {
                "id": 10519,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "May 23 : Instagram",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10520": {
                "id": 10520,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "May 23 : LinkedIn",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10521": {
                "id": 10521,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "May 23 : YouTube",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10522": {
                "id": 10522,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "May 23 : Health Unlocked",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "346": {
              "10517": {
                "id": 10517,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "June 23 : Twitter",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10518": {
                "id": 10518,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "June 23 : Facebook",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10519": {
                "id": 10519,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "June 23 : Instagram",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10520": {
                "id": 10520,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "June 23 : LinkedIn",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10521": {
                "id": 10521,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "June 23 : YouTube",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10522": {
                "id": 10522,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 343,
                "question": "June 23 : Health Unlocked",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 16,
          "shown": false
        },
        "365": {
          "id": 365,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "Number of times both EGG and chickens are mentioned together in media coverage",
          "subquestions": {
            "366": {
              "10601": {
                "id": 10601,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Fundraising : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10602": {
                "id": 10602,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Fundraising : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10715": {
                "id": 10715,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Fundraising : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "367": {
              "10601": {
                "id": 10601,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Education  : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10602": {
                "id": 10602,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Education  : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10715": {
                "id": 10715,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Education  : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "368": {
              "10601": {
                "id": 10601,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Social Care : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10602": {
                "id": 10602,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Social Care : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10715": {
                "id": 10715,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Social Care : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "369": {
              "10601": {
                "id": 10601,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Employment : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10602": {
                "id": 10602,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Employment : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10715": {
                "id": 10715,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Employment : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "370": {
              "10601": {
                "id": 10601,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Healthcare : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10602": {
                "id": 10602,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Healthcare : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10715": {
                "id": 10715,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Healthcare : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "371": {
              "10601": {
                "id": 10601,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Total : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10602": {
                "id": 10602,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Total : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10715": {
                "id": 10715,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Total : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "465": {
              "10601": {
                "id": 10601,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Other : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10602": {
                "id": 10602,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Other : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10715": {
                "id": 10715,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 365,
                "question": "Other : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 25,
          "shown": false
        },
        "396": {
          "id": 396,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "Number of influencing coalitions and partnerships that EGG is part of",
          "subquestions": {
            "397": {
              "10605": {
                "id": 10605,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "England : Coalitions",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10606": {
                "id": 10606,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "England : National Partnerships",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10607": {
                "id": 10607,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "England : Local Partnerships",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "398": {
              "10605": {
                "id": 10605,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "Wales : Coalitions",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10606": {
                "id": 10606,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "Wales : National Partnerships",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10607": {
                "id": 10607,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "Wales : Local Partnerships",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "399": {
              "10605": {
                "id": 10605,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "Northern Ireland : Coalitions",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10606": {
                "id": 10606,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "Northern Ireland : National Partnerships",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10607": {
                "id": 10607,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 396,
                "question": "Northern Ireland : Local Partnerships",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 25,
          "shown": false
        },
        "468": {
          "id": 468,
          "type": "parent",
          "question": "% of colleagues from under-represented EGG groups",
          "subquestions": {
            "469": {
              "10875": {
                "id": 10875,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Asian : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10876": {
                "id": 10876,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Asian : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10877": {
                "id": 10877,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Asian : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10878": {
                "id": 10878,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Asian : Total 22/23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "471": {
              "10875": {
                "id": 10875,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Black : April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10876": {
                "id": 10876,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Black : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10877": {
                "id": 10877,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Black : June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10878": {
                "id": 10878,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Black : Total 22/23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "472": {
              "10875": {
                "id": 10875,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Learning: April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10876": {
                "id": 10876,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Learning: May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10877": {
                "id": 10877,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Learning: June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10878": {
                "id": 10878,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Learning: Total 22/23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            },
            "473": {
              "10875": {
                "id": 10875,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "EGGs: April 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10876": {
                "id": 10876,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "EGGS : May 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10877": {
                "id": 10877,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "EGGS: June 23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              },
              "10878": {
                "id": 10878,
                "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX",
                "parent": 468,
                "question": "Eggs : Total 22/23",
                "answer": null,
                "shown": false
              }
            }
          },
          "section_id": 29,
          "shown": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Technically, you can only loop through arrays and looking through your JSON, you only have a single (populated) array with a single item. No easy answer for what you want given you don’t want to pay for a third party connector. You’re on your own buddy. You could use Azure Functions or the inline JS operation but you need to be able to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @Skin and AFAIK, without adding a third party connector or inline script execution flattening is not possible:

**`Design:`**

[image]

In below script i have flattened a few properties:

```
function flattenOb(obj) {
  const res = {};

  function rec(current, prop) {
    if (Object(current) !== current || Array.isArray(current)) {
      res[prop] = current;
    } else {
      for (const key in current) {
        if (current.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          rec(current[key], prop ? `${prop}.${key}` : key);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  rec(obj, '');

  return res;
}

const myjson = workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body

const result = flattenOb(myjson);
return result;
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

In the above script i could able to to flatten few, but I agree with @Skin that you need to able to code a script to flatten your entire json(as I have taken sample of it and tried), or use Azure Function App.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you an answer that you may not like but I'm going to provide it anyway.  It may help someone else or give you a head start if you choose to go down the path of using a custom connector or Azure Functions.

[image: Flow]

The flow I've provided uses the **C# Script Execute** operation from the **Advanced Data Operations** connector.  This allows you to run small snippets of C# without having to spin up an Azure Function.

Your JSON is contained within the `Initialize JSON` step.

This is the code ...

```
JObject data = JObject.FromObject(parameters.Data);

var answers = data.Descendants().OfType<JObject>().Where(x => x.ContainsKey("id") && x.ContainsKey("type") && x.Property("type").Value.ToString() != "parent").ToList<dynamic>();

return answers
```

... and these were the parameters passed in ...

```
{
  "Data": @{variables('JSON')}
}
```

***Note:** I made an assumption on the specifics of what you wanted to "flatten", if I'm wrong, it can easily be tweaked.*

**Result**

This is the JSON it will return ...

```
{
  "returnValue": [
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10012,
      "parent": 6,
      "question": "April 23 : All ages",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10013,
      "parent": 6,
      "question": "April 23 : Children",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10012,
      "parent": 6,
      "question": "May 23 : All ages",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10013,
      "parent": 6,
      "question": "May 23 : Children",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10012,
      "parent": 6,
      "question": "June 23 : All ages",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10013,
      "parent": 6,
      "question": "June 23 : Children",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "question": "Age-standardised avoidable shopping",
      "section_id": 3,
      "shown": false,
      "type": "TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10032,
      "parent": 25,
      "question": "Please complete the following: : Number of question responses",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10033,
      "parent": 25,
      "question": "Please complete the following: : Number of 'Very good' responses",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10035,
      "parent": 25,
      "question": "Please complete the following: : Number of 'Good' responses",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": "Jayne Thomas",
      "answer_id": 10477,
      "id": 28,
      "question": "who are you?",
      "section_id": 10,
      "shown": true,
      "type": "MENU"
    },
    {
      "answer": "Yes, I am the EGG",
      "answer_id": 10048,
      "id": 35,
      "question": "Are you an EGG?",
      "section_id": 10,
      "shown": true,
      "type": "RADIO"
    },
    {
      "id": 58,
      "question": "What is the name of the initiative that you are reporting EGG for?",
      "section_id": 10,
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MENU"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10200,
      "parent": 179,
      "question": "2019/20 : Women",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10201,
      "parent": 179,
      "question": "2019/20 : Men",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10438,
      "parent": 272,
      "question": "April 23 : Total number of people consulted",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10438,
      "parent": 272,
      "question": "May 23 : Total number of people consulted",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10438,
      "parent": 272,
      "question": "June 23 : Total number of people consulted",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "id": 273,
      "question": "What is the name of your EGG project?",
      "section_id": 10,
      "shown": false,
      "type": "TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10517,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "April 23 : Twitter",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10518,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "April 23 : Facebook",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10519,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "April 23 : Instagram",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10520,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "April 23 : LinkedIn",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10521,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "April 23 : YouTube",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10522,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "April 23 : Health Unlocked",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10517,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "May 23 : Twitter",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10518,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "May 23 : Facebook",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10519,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "May 23 : Instagram",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10520,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "May 23 : LinkedIn",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10521,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "May 23 : YouTube",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10522,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "May 23 : Health Unlocked",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10517,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "June 23 : Twitter",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10518,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "June 23 : Facebook",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10519,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "June 23 : Instagram",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10520,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "June 23 : LinkedIn",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10521,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "June 23 : YouTube",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10522,
      "parent": 343,
      "question": "June 23 : Health Unlocked",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10601,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Fundraising : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10602,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Fundraising : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10715,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Fundraising : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10601,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Education  : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10602,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Education  : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10715,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Education  : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10601,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Social Care : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10602,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Social Care : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10715,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Social Care : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10601,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Employment : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10602,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Employment : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10715,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Employment : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10601,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Healthcare : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10602,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Healthcare : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10715,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Healthcare : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10601,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Total : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10602,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Total : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10715,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Total : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10601,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Other : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10602,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Other : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10715,
      "parent": 365,
      "question": "Other : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10605,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "England : Coalitions",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10606,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "England : National Partnerships",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10607,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "England : Local Partnerships",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10605,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "Wales : Coalitions",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10606,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "Wales : National Partnerships",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10607,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "Wales : Local Partnerships",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10605,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "Northern Ireland : Coalitions",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10606,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "Northern Ireland : National Partnerships",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10607,
      "parent": 396,
      "question": "Northern Ireland : Local Partnerships",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10875,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Asian : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10876,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Asian : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10877,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Asian : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10878,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Asian : Total 22/23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10875,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Black : April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10876,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Black : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10877,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Black : June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10878,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Black : Total 22/23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10875,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Learning: April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10876,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Learning: May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10877,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Learning: June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10878,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Learning: Total 22/23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10875,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "EGGs: April 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10876,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "EGGS : May 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10877,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "EGGS: June 23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    },
    {
      "answer": null,
      "id": 10878,
      "parent": 468,
      "question": "Eggs : Total 22/23",
      "shown": false,
      "type": "MULTI_TEXTBOX"
    }
  ],
  "log": []
}
```